# How to minimize a jFrame when the window close button is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to minimize the JFrame when the close button is pressed, I am using the code shown below, but whenever I press the close button, the frame first minimizes and then closes automatically. I am working on Ubuntu.

**How can I prevent the JFrame from closing?**

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        final Gui frame = new Gui();

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                frame.setExtendedState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Normally this would be `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)`. But your code includes the `Gui` class, which is not a standard Swing class. Is this a custom subclass of `JFrame`?

Comment: So, what's being set in the Gui class?

Comment: Gui class extends JFrame, I tried JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE but it even removes the icon of the application from the application bar .. so this way i have no possibility to maximize it again, is there any other way?

Comment: You should use Swing components, not extend them, unless you're overriding one of the component methods.  Did you try DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE?  How does the user actually close your application?  Task manager?

Comment: no, i want to minimize the app when the default close button is pressed, the user can exit with an exit the application option in the menu where i simply use System.exit(0)

Comment: What you are trying to do is counter-intuitive to the user.  When I want to minimize a frame I'll use the `_` button in the top right of the application frame.  If I click the `X` I expect the app. to *get the hell off my screen..*  I pity your 3 users (the rest will uninstall the app. and demand a refund).

Comment: I really appreciate your concern for my users but that is not how the app is supposed to work, my app is a scheduler so i dont really want the users to exit the app but just to minimize it so that the can get alert for their alarms or tasks at the required time :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try maybe this way

```
final Gui frame = new Gui();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);// <- prevent closing
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
    }
});

frame.setSize(200,200);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This will prevent window from closing, and your current code will minimize it (at least this is how it works on Win7, let me know if it helps or not).

Comment: I just tried, well it does nothing now when i press the close button but application does not minimize either

Comment: This is very nice.  It prevents the `X` (Close button) from doing nothing which is what most online recommendations propose.  Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and it animates back to the taskbar as expected.